Negaim, definition of "poreach", spreading completely
The Torah in discussing tzoraas gives a remarkable law about its spreading (Vayikra 12:9-17):

נֶ֣גַע צָרַ֔עַת כִּ֥י תִהְיֶ֖ה בְּאָדָ֑ם וְהוּבָ֖א אֶל־הַכֹּהֵֽן׃
וְרָאָ֣ה הַכֹּהֵ֗ן וְהִנֵּ֤ה שְׂאֵת־לְבָנָה֙ בָּע֔וֹר וְהִ֕יא הָפְכָ֖ה
שֵׂעָ֣ר לָבָ֑ן וּמִֽחְיַ֛ת בָּשָׂ֥ר חַ֖י בַּשְׂאֵֽת׃  צָרַ֨עַת
נוֹשֶׁ֤נֶת הִוא֙ בְּע֣וֹר בְּשָׂר֔וֹ וְטִמְּא֖וֹ הַכֹּהֵ֑ן לֹ֣א
יַסְגִּרֶ֔נּוּ כִּ֥י טָמֵ֖א הֽוּא׃  וְאִם־פָּר֨וֹחַ תִּפְרַ֤ח
הַצָּרַ֙עַת֙ בָּע֔וֹר וְכִסְּתָ֣ה הַצָּרַ֗עַת אֵ֚ת כׇּל־ע֣וֹר
הַנֶּ֔גַע מֵרֹאשׁ֖וֹ וְעַד־רַגְלָ֑יו לְכׇל־מַרְאֵ֖ה עֵינֵ֥י הַכֹּהֵֽן׃
וְרָאָ֣ה הַכֹּהֵ֗ן וְהִנֵּ֨ה כִסְּתָ֤ה הַצָּרַ֙עַת֙
אֶת־כׇּל־בְּשָׂר֔וֹ וְטִהַ֖ר אֶת־הַנָּ֑גַע כֻּלּ֛וֹ הָפַ֥ךְ לָבָ֖ן
טָה֥וֹר הֽוּא׃  וּבְי֨וֹם הֵרָא֥וֹת בּ֛וֹ בָּשָׂ֥ר חַ֖י יִטְמָֽא׃
וְרָאָ֧ה הַכֹּהֵ֛ן אֶת־הַבָּשָׂ֥ר הַחַ֖י וְטִמְּא֑וֹ הַבָּשָׂ֥ר הַחַ֛י
טָמֵ֥א ה֖וּא צָרַ֥עַת הֽוּא׃  א֣וֹ כִ֥י יָשׁ֛וּב הַבָּשָׂ֥ר הַחַ֖י
וְנֶהְפַּ֣ךְ לְלָבָ֑ן וּבָ֖א אֶל־הַכֹּהֵֽן׃  וְרָאָ֙הוּ֙ הַכֹּהֵ֔ן
וְהִנֵּ֛ה נֶהְפַּ֥ךְ הַנֶּ֖גַע לְלָבָ֑ן וְטִהַ֧ר הַכֹּהֵ֛ן
אֶת־הַנֶּ֖גַע טָה֥וֹר הֽוּא׃
...If the eruption spreads out over the skin so that it covers all the
skin [of the affected person] from head to foot, wherever the priest can
see—  if the priest sees that the eruption has covered the whole
body—he shall pronounce as pure the affected person, who is pure from
having turned all white.  But as soon as undiscolored flesh appears in
it, that person shall be impure;...

Throughout Masechet Negaim, I took for granted what I thought was the obvious meaning of פורח, namely, the nega spreading to cover the person's entire body - as translated here. This (usually) makes the person tahor, even though he is now completely covered by the nega.
I was surprised to see the Tosefos in Niddah 19a ד"ה מה להלן, who originally understood it very differently:

מה להלן פרחה בכולו טהור. מדמדמה פריחה דאדם לפריחת בגדים הא דכתיב
(ויקרא י״ג:י״ב) וכסתה הצרעת את כל עור הנגע מראשו ועד רגליו אגופו של
אדם קאי אע"ג דפשטיה דקרא משמע דאנגע קאי דאיירי לעיל בנגע שנטמא על ידי
שיש בו מחיית בשר חי ועליה קאי וכסתה הצרעת את כל עור הנגע מראשו של נגע
עד רגליו כלומר עד סופו אבל הכא משמע דקאי אאדם דומיא דבגד וכן מוכח בכמה
מקומות בת"כ ובריש איזהו מקומן (זבחים מט:):
...even though the simple meaning of the verses implies that [the
spreading] goes on the nega itself: Above the section was dealing with a nega
that became tamei because it contained a "michyah" (healthy flesh),
and on this it says that afterward the nega covered the entire skin of
the nega, from its head to its foot, that is, till the other end.
But this gemara implies that it goes on the [whole] person, similar to
the tzoraas on clothing (which does not have a din of michyah at
all)... This is also implied in many places in Toras Cohanim...

Tosefos HaRosh there has a similar discussion. They are making an interesting point: How do we read the words את כל עור הנגע, which doesn't sound like the person's whole body? (See Malbim there.)
Still and all, I'm astonished at their claim that this gemara is the source for reading it the way we read it (and Toras Cohanim; can someone tell me what they see in the source from Zevachim?) After all, there is a whole perek of the Mishnah talking about פורח, the 8th perek of Negaim. Is it possible to read that according to what they call the simple reading of the Torah? (Mishnah 2 there is an easy example; there must be others.)
